# When connecting to Oracle DB I get External: SIGSEGV error

Tags: freepascal, lazarus

I'll say how I reproduce the problem on lazarus.
I have a form and a datamodule using zeos to enstablish a connection with a local oracle db.
The problem born when I put some code to interlocute with the db.
Here is an example:

```
OracleMng.ZQuery1.SQL.Clear;
```

That is exactly the line going in error.
Here is the full code of the form:

```
 unit form1;

    {$mode objfpc}{$H+}
    
    interface
    
    uses
      Classes, SysUtils, Forms, Controls, Graphics, Dialogs, DBGrids, StdCtrls,
      datamodule2;
    
    type
    
      { TLogin }
    
      TLogin = class(TForm)
        Button1: TButton;
        DBGrid1: TDBGrid;
        procedure Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
      private
    
      public
    
      end;
    
    var
      Login: TLogin;
    
    implementation
    
    {$R *.lfm}
    
    { TLogin }
    
    procedure TLogin.Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
    begin
    
      OracleMng.ZQuery1.SQL.Clear;
    
    end;
    
    end.
```

Here is the code of the datamodule:

```
unit datamodule2;

{$mode objfpc}{$H+}

interface

uses
  Classes, SysUtils, DB, ZConnection, ZDataset, ZSqlMonitor;

type

  { TOracleMng }

  TOracleMng = class(TDataModule)
    DataSource1: TDataSource;
    ZConnection1: TZConnection;
    ZQuery1: TZQuery;
  private

  public

  end;

var
  OracleMng: TOracleMng;

implementation

{$R *.lfm}

{ TOracleMng }



end.
```

I'm trying

```
    if (OracleMng <>  Nil) and (OracleMng.Zquery1 <> Nil) then OracleMng.ZQuery1.SQL.add('select * from help');
  if (OracleMng <>  Nil) and (OracleMng.Zquery1 <> Nil) then OracleMng.ZQuery1.ExecSQL;
   dbgrid1.refresh;
```

I have no more errors but the DBGrid1 is not filled.

This is my project lpr file:

```
program project1;

{$mode objfpc}{$H+}

uses
  {$IFDEF UNIX}{$IFDEF UseCThreads}
  cthreads,
  {$ENDIF}{$ENDIF}
  Interfaces, // this includes the LCL widgetset
  Forms, zcomponent, datamodule2, form1
  { you can add units after this };

{$R *.res}

begin
  RequireDerivedFormResource:=True;
  Application.Scaled:=True;
  Application.Initialize;
  Application.CreateForm(TLogin, Login);
  Application.Run;
end.
```

Comment: The most likely  reason to get that error is if OracleMng or ZQuery1 has not been created. Change your code to `if (OracleMng <>  Nil) and (OracleMng.Zquery1 <> Nil) then OracleMng.ZQuery1.SQL.Clear`.  Do you still get the error?

Comment: @MartynA It's not giving the error but the DBGrid1 don't show me the result of the query. I am using dbgrid1.refresh;  
But now for each query I should do that "if"?

Comment: I think you need to add a [minimal, reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) to your q, including the query that you expect to populate the DBGrid.

Comment: I added the 3 lines I am using in the question. In Delphi I used this code and it was working (using dbexpress):    

DataModule1.SQLQuery1.Close;
  DataModule1.SQLQuery1.SQL.Clear;
  DataModule1.SQLQuery1.sql.add('update help set topic = :topic where info like :called');
  DataModule1.SQLQuery1.ParamByName('topic').AsString := 'LAKO';//uso per forza ParamByName 
  DataModule1.SQLQuery1.ParamByName('called').AsString := '%called from the local%';
  DataModule1.SQLQuery1.ExecSQL;

Comment: The same does not work on lazarus with zeos connect.

Comment: ExecSQL does not return a result set (i.e. the records which would be displayed in the DBGrid).  So after calling ExecSQL to execute the update, you need to set the SQL back to some SELECT query which returns a result set and then call SQLQuery1.Open.

Comment: if (OracleMng <>  Nil) and (OracleMng.Zquery1 <> Nil) then
   oraclemng.zquery1.SQL.add('select * from help');
       oraclemng.zquery1.execsql;
       oraclemng.zquery1.open;

  dbgrid1.refresh;

Comment: I reaaly don't think you understand what you are doing.  For a single SQL statement, you either call ExecSQL  or Open, not both.  Which one to calls depends on what the SQL does, but with a SELECT statement, you use Open.  In your case you need Open to get the records to display in the DBGrid.  And in that case you don't need dbgrid1.refresh - it will be automatica;ly refrefresh when Open is called in ZQuery1.  I'm out of here now until tomorrow.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The fact that the change I suggested in my comment, namely

```
if (OracleMng <>  Nil) and (OracleMng.Zquery1 <> Nil) then
  OracleMng.ZQuery1.SQL.Clear
```

evidently stopped you getting the SIGSEGV error suggests that your DataModule and
form are being created in the wrong order, i.e. form first.  Check this out by going to
Project | View Source in the IDE.  If you see something like

```
program MyProgram;

[...]

begin
  Application.Initialize;
  Application.MainFormOnTaskbar := True;
  Application.CreateForm(TForm1, Form1);
  Application.CreateForm(TDataModule1, DataModule1);
  Application.Run;
end.
```

they are in the wrong order, so swap the two CreateForm lines

```
  Application.CreateForm(TDataModule1, DataModule1);
  Application.CreateForm(TForm1, Form1);
```

With that change, you should no longer need the

```
if (OracleMng <>  Nil) and (OracleMng.Zquery1 <> Nil) then`
```

Next thing:  You seem to be confused about when to use

```
ZQuery1.ExecSQL
```

and

```
ZQuery1.Open
```

`Open` is intended for when the SQL statement you are using produces a result set, that is
a collection of records which can be viewed in a TDBGrid.  The most usual way  to do this
is to use a SELECT statement  as in

```
ZQuery1.SQL.Text := 'select * from MyTable';
ZQuery1.Open;
```

`ExecQuery` is intended for use where your SQL statement performs some operation on the database
which does not involve SELECTing records.  The most common SQL statements which need ExecSQL are

```
UPDATE
INSERT
DELETE
```

though there are others, for example statements which execute stored procedures on the SQL Server
(note that some stored procedures return result sets and so need `Open`, rather than ExecSQL).

Note that ExecSQL will clear out any records which are in the dataset (ZQuery1) so after
you need to do Open again using a suitable SQL statement

```
var
  S : String;
begin
  S := 'update MyTable set number = number +1 where id = 5';
  ZQuery.SQL.Text := S;
  ZQuery1.ExecSQL;    // no records shown in DBGrid1 from here

  S := 'select * from MyTable';
  ZQuery.SQL.Text := S;
  ZQuery1.Open;    // records shown in DBGrid1 again
end;
```

Note that I do

```
  S := 'select * from MyTable';
  ZQuery.SQL.Text := S;
```

instead of

```
  ZQuery1.SQL.Clear;
  ZQuery1.SQL.Add('select * from myTable');
```

The reason for this is that it's much easier to see the whole SQL statement in the debugger by
inspecting the variable `S`  than inspecting the ZQuery1.SQL.Text property and much easier to
see any syntax errors.

You should always `Close` a dataset that you've `Open`ed once you have finished working with it as it ensures what the data on disk is up to date. if the last SQL operation was ExecSQL, you don't need to close the dataset.

If you set the query's Text property the way I do, with ZQuery1.SQL.Text, you don't need to uses `Clear`. In any case, it is only equivalent to doing `ZQuery1.SQL.Text := ''` and it does not affect the state of the dataset - it only does anything when you call `ExecSQL` or `Open`.

Comment: This is my project lpr file:
program project1;

{$mode objfpc}{$H+}

uses
  {$IFDEF UNIX}{$IFDEF UseCThreads}
  cthreads,
  {$ENDIF}{$ENDIF}
  Interfaces, // this includes the LCL widgetset
  Forms, zcomponent, datamodule2, form1
  { you can add units after this };

{$R *.res}

begin
  RequireDerivedFormResource:=True;
  Application.Scaled:=True;
  Application.Initialize;
  Application.CreateForm(TLogin, Login);
  Application.Run;
end.

Comment: That code doesn't create your datamodule, which it should do, **before** it creates your Login form.

Comment: I added it to the 'question' for a well formatting. Anyway I noticed that thanks to your answer but if feeled me strange why lazarus didn't do that automatically (to put the create datamodule line in that file). I'll write that and recompile. Thanks

Comment: it all works fine now. You have been truly precious! Your examples finally solved me a lot of doubts. I'd like to know also when to use .close and .clear after executing queries.

Comment: You should always Close a dataset that you've Opened once you have finished working with it as it ensures what the data on disk is up to date.  if the last SQL operation was ExecSQL, you don't need to close the datassetIf you set the query's Text property the way I do, with ZQuery1.SQL.Text, you don't need to uses Clear.  In any case, it is only equivalent to setting ZQuery1.SQL.Text := '.  ' and it does not affect the state of the dataset - it only does anything when you call ExecSQL or Open.